# Displaying TkInter output inline in Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, tkinter, ipython, jupyter

I'm trying to create a simple real time drawing application in Python using the TkInter library, and I need it to display **inline** as a Jupyter notebooks output, as opposed to in a new window.
So far, my test application does exactly what I need it to do but tkinter opens a new window when I run it in Jupyter IPython:

```
 from tkinter import *
 import time

root = Tk()
root.title = "Laser Drawing"
root.resizable(0,0)
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
centerX = 100
centerY = 100
radius = 2
resolution = [1280, 720]

canvas = Canvas(root, width=resolution[0], height=resolution[1], bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()

def drawCircle():
    circle = canvas.create_oval(centerX-radius, centerY+radius, centerX+radius, centerY-radius, fill="red", outline="red")

for i in range (0, 1000):
    drawCircle()
    root.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
    centerX+=1
    centerY+=1
```

Is there any way of **making the output generated by tkinter display inline**, without needing to open a new window?
Alternatively, what libraries could I consider using to create a similar interactive drawing program that would display inline? I've tried using Jupyter's javascript/HTML magics, which does display a canvas inline, but I want to be able to achieve this in Python.

Comment: Can you add exactly the code you are using?

Comment: @RickM. Sorry, I accidentally submitted before including code. The code's there now.

Comment: `jsfiddle` is a good alternative
http://jsfiddle.net/Zv57N/

Comment: Here is an other workaround: https://github.com/mkrphys/ipython-tikzmagic